# general procedure for contour integration of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{Ai}(x)^{n} dx$

Tags: special-functions, contour-integration

In [Richard Crandall](http://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/crandall/)'s [On The Quantum Zeta Function](http://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/crandall/papers/a62111.pdf), following eq. 4.11:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{Ai}(x)^{2}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{5}{6})}{2\pi^{5/6}12^{1/6}}
$$

“again derivable by contour integration”

- Which contour? (for this)
- Can the contour be generalized for for $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{Ai}(x)^{n} dx$?

Comment: $\operatorname{Ai}(x)^2$ actually has a simple antiderivative, $\int \operatorname{Ai}(x)^2 \, dx = x\operatorname{Ai}(x)^2-\operatorname{Ai}'(x)^2$. Sadly this doesn't generalise to higher powers.